# currently_playing not working when using the Spotipy library

Tags: python, api, spotify, spotipy

I'm trying to access music that the user is currently playing using the spotipy Spotify python library.

```
import json
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials 

cid = "xxx"
csecret = "xxx"
redirectURI = "xxx"
username = "xxx"

client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id=cid, client_secret=csecret) 
sp = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)

scope = 'user-read-currently-playing'
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope, cid, csecret, redirectURI)

if token:
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
else:
    print("Can't get token for", username)

current_track = sp.current_user_playing_track()
print(json.dumps(current_track, sort_keys=False, indent=4))
```

I've also tried using `sp.currently_playing()`. I am able to access other data such as `sp.current_user_saved_tracks(limit=3, offset=0)`. Using what I currently have, it always errors out saying
`AttributeError: 'Spotify' object has no attribute 'current_user_playing_track'`. I've explored using node instead but I really would like to stick with python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use a feature that isn't in the latest released version yet.

You can see [on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/spotipy) that the current version was released on 5 Jan 2017, but you can see [on Github](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/commit/9d47b98eabb054b47b0df9d38dfee411ebf72493) that the function you want to call was added on 13 May 2017.

[Issue #270](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/issues/270) and [Issue #211](https://github.com/plamere/spotipy/issues/211) are both asking when a new release will be pushed to PyPI, (Also, there's some weird issue with the version numbering.)

Anyway, as #211 says:

> If you're running into issues still, you can install the package directly from the github repo.

```
pip install git+https://github.com/plamere/spotipy.git --upgrade
```

Comment: It works for python 2 but not python 3. I'm currently trying to use pip3 and find solutions on why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

So I have been trying to acces my current song too, after 3 days following every wrong answer on the web...
I am using the `Authorization Code Flow` as said here [https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.12.0/#client-credentials-flow](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.12.0/#authorization-code-flow).

> Only endpoints that do not access user information can be accessed

As I couldn't set the environement variables, I did it with another script.

**Note that you should add a redirection link such as "https://localhost:8000/"** in https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard/applications/.

---

Here is my code to add my creditentials:

```
import os

class SetCreditentials:

    def __init__(self):
        self.CLIENT_SECRET = os.getenv('SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET')
        self.CLIENT_ID = os.getenv('SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID')
        self.REDIRECT_URI = os.getenv('SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI')
        os.environ['SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID'] = ""
        os.environ['SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET'] = ""
        os.environ['SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI'] = "http://localhost:8000/"
```

---

Here is the code to access any data (the current playing track here):

```
import spotipy.util as util
import spotipy
import Creditentials

# Authorization Code Flow
user = "213tzif5o7rzyxtijuqdgtfuq"
scope = "user-read-currently-playing"

Creditentials.SetCreditentials()
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(user, scope)
track = spotipy.Spotify(token).current_user_playing_track()
print(track)
```